# MongoDB count number of times an item is referenced in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

Take the following models:

A Question (like, a stack question!)

```
Question {
    _id : ObjectId(123),
    Question : "MongoDB: Count number of referenced items",
    Tags : [ObjectId(1), ObjectId(2), ObjectId(3)] 
}
```

A table of tags

```
Tag{
    _id : ObjectId(1),
    tag : "MongoDB",
    description : "stuff"
},
{
 .... more tags
}
```

I would like to list all the tags, and next to each tag show a count of how many times that tag is used. You can then click on the tag to edit it, like so:

```
MongoDB (1232)
C# (23232)
```

Whats the most robust way to do this. I have investigated the following.

1. Aggregation framework. 
   This enables me to get a count of how many times the ObjectId appeared in the Question table, but I have no easy way of getting the name of the tag. I guess I would have to do another database call, get all the tags then map them together.
2. Have a COUNT on the tags table, and every time I submit a question check to see if a tag has been added or removed then increment or decrement this counter. I cant seem to get my brain to accept this is a good way to do this.

[Edit - see comments]

1. Store tag names in the question. Use tag name is Id. This would allow #1 to work a better. Tag names May change however, so i guess this has knock-on effects.

Which of these would people recommend (and why). Are there any strategies I have missed?

I am using the mongo driver for C#

Comment: One obvious way would be to store the tag names in the question. I can't from your example see any reason that the name would be a worse reference to the `Tag` table than the ObjectId is.

Comment: I thought of that too, but lets assume tag names might change - would that still be a good idea? what if tags were more than one word (I might not have used the best example)

Comment: also - in mongo is it not best practice to use ObjectId as Ids for everything - to aid scalabilty

Comment: Wrote an answer instead to summarise the approach.

Comment: there is no question that the answer given is the only reasonable way to do this.  I don't see what you can possibly gain by normalizing this like you would in a relational database when you don't have joins and it seems strange to optimize schema for something that *might* happen very infrequently (changing tag name) rather than for something that you do all the time (get totals by name of tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make 2 queries to mongo to get C# lists of each collection.

```
List<Question> questions = YourGetQuestionListFunction();
List<Tag> tags = YourGetTagListFunction();
```

Then make an in memory linq query on these C# collections and return a custom object with only the properties you want (including a question count). e.g.

```
var result = from t in tags
select new {
TagId = t._id,
TagName = t.tag,
Description = t.description,
QuestionCount = questions.Where(x => x.Tags != null && x.Tags.Contains(t.Id)).Count()
}
```

Comment: After some consideration, I went with this. Having a string name as the Id, where in some circumstances would be great, wasn't great for me.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient approach I can think of given this limited view of the system is to save the tag name in the collection instead of the `ObjectId`. That would have the advantage that your group by/count would be one single aggregate operation, and I can't see why `ObjectId` would be a better identifier of a tag than the name would be (assuming the name is unique)

The downside is that the rename of a tag would be a two part operation instead of a one part. You'd have to first rename it in the `tags` table, then rename it in the `questions` table in all `Tags` arrays using something like;

```
db.questions.update({'Tags':"Old Name"},{$set:{'Tags.$':'New Name'}})
```

Given that a count probably is a more frequent operation, I'd say that doing that operation in a single call to MongoDB while increasing the rename to two separate operations should be a definite net gain.